# Amend git merge with rebase

Tags: git

## tl;dr

I have done a `master -> feature` merge to update and resolve conflicts before the actual merge.
Can I rebase feature onto master instead and apply the conflict resolution from the merge?

What I have:

```
o               - TODO merge feature -> master
|\
| o     feature - "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into feature"
|/|
o |     master         
| o             - "Implement some new feature here"
| |
...
|/  
o
```

What I want:

```
o               - TODO merge feature -> master
|\
| o     feature - "Implement some new feature here"
|/
o       master         
|
...
|
o
```

## Long version

I want to merge a feature branch that is quite old and has conflicts, because other work was merged to master in the mean time. First I updated the feature branch from master by a `master -> feature` merge. Now I am able to successfully merge the feature branch back without conflicts. But looking at he history now, I realised I should have *rebased* my feature onto the latest master instead. Unfortunatelly I had to resolve quite an amount of conflicts, can I reuse the current state?

Comment: No, I don't think you can reuse the current state.  While similar conflicts would probably occur in the course of a rebase, they would happen at different points, as each of your commits is reapplied.  So, I vote for just redoing things using a rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim Biegeleisen commented, you can't reuse the merge commit (which is where you resolved your conflicts) in a rebase *directly*.

The merge conflicts are resolved in a the merge commit, which will drop off when you do the `rebase master` command.

However, if there merge conflicts were especially painful and/or if you only have a few commits that you're working with, you could follow a workflow of:

- merge `master` into feature
- resolve conflicts
- do a soft reset of your feature branch
- stash the changes
- rebase master
- replay your stash
- recreate your commits

By doing the soft reset, the actual file changes *after* the merge are preserved so you won't need to resolve the conflicts the way you'd need to do if you were just rebasing.

Comment: This looks promising. I only have one commit, but it contains lots of changes. I could do a soft reset, then revert the work - this should yield the conflict resolution alone right? I will play with it a bit.

Comment: It wont yield the conflict resolution *alone*, it'll contain the original work *and* the conflict resolution - which sounds like exactly what you what especially since there's only one commit.

Comment: And I realized I didn't fully explain the steps - the trick is once you've done your soft reset, then you can stash the changes and then get your feature branch up to date with master (ie rebase), re-apply the stash and then you'll have all of your working changes, at which point you can then recreate your commits and you should be good to go